# Unable to add angular component inside nodeJS express project

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, components

I am new to node with angular.

I created a new express project, and then added a new folder called `assets`.

I ran the following commands:

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli

npm cache clean

npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
```

Then I went to assets folder and tried to create an angular component:

`ng generate component app`

And i've got the following error:

> Unable to find "@angular/cli" in devDependencies.
>
> Please take the following steps to avoid issues: "npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest"
>
> Unable to find any apps in `.angular-cli.json`.

What is the error here ?

Comment: usually to create a new component with angular-cli you need to create an angular project with the `ng new [projectName]` commands

Comment: Inside the express project ? But I already installed the cli inside my project. Can you help me with that ?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki

That's basicaly how you're supposed to use angular-cli. Actually your problem is that angular-cli with the `ng new` command create all the file it needs to run and since you didn't use this command to create an angular app you can't create a component with `ng generate component`. I don't know how you're supposed to merge your angular project in your express project ... but at least I pointed where your problem is.

Comment: may I ask why you need this express project ?

Comment: I am taking a best seller course on Udemy, where teacher combining angular with nodeJS and mongoDB. He added a component but he didn't say how and didn't answer the question. I am trying now, lets see. By the way @mJehanno I am learning, is it wrong to merge between the two ?

Comment: Lots of people are speaking about MEAN stack (mongo, express, angular, node), because it give to develoopers a full javascript workflow. So basically I think you can use them all together, but I don't know how yet (learning angular too). In my opinion i would just create a rest api using express and mongo and have angular has a client. I think you can use the express app to have your angular server side rendered. I'll seek more infos around mean stack.